# Clean old workbox cache in a SPA served by Pyramid

Tags: caching, pyramid, progressive-web-apps, workbox, preact

I'm new to PWAs and service workers. I started to test workbox with a Pyramid application which serves a preact app bundled with webpack 4. This is the `home.jinja2` template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{request.locale_name}}">
  <head>
    ...
    <link href="{{request.static_url('app:static/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{request.static_url('app:static/runtime.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{request.static_url('app:static/vendor.js')}}"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"/>

    {% block scripts %}
    {% endblock %}

    <script type="text/javascript">
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The SPA makes calls to `/api/v1/`. I want to provide a network first experience. This is part of the webpack config:

```
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk,
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'app', 'static')),
  },
  plugins: [
    new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
      cssProcessorOptions: { discardComments: { removeAll: true } },
      canPrint: false,
    }),
    new ManifestPlugin({
      publicPath: '',
    }),
    new WebpackCleanupPlugin({
      exclude: [
        'robots.txt',
      ],
    }),
    new GenerateSW({
      clientsClaim: true,
      skipWaiting: true,
      runtimeCaching: [
        {
          urlPattern: /\//,
          handler: 'networkFirst',
        },
        {
          urlPattern: /https:\/\/fonts.(?:googleapis|gstatic).com\/(.*)/,
          handler: 'staleWhileRevalidate',
        },
      ],
      navigateFallback: '/app-shell',
      navigateFallbackBlacklist: [/^\/api/],
      templatedUrls: {
        '/app-shell': 'index.html',
      },
    }),
  ],
```

The generated `index.html` basically equals to the `home.jinja2` layout (both contain the hashed assets urls). The problem I face is whenever I make changes to the frontend and deploy them, once the update process of the service worker is completed, the browser **requests both the new and old assets** (43f6a4e6 is the hash of the new assets).

[image: network_requests]

Refreshing has no effect at all, even after 24 hours. I delete old assets on every deployment, therefore all requests to old assets error and a blank page is displayed. I temporarily had to redirect old assets requests to the new ones.

I implemented this recipe https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#warm_the_runtime_cache and the site is completely broken. Firefox displays a data corrupted error. Any ideas would be much appreciated.